# Autocomplete com jquery e mysql não lista as opções ao começar a digitar

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-ui

Tenho o seguinte formulário:

```
<?php
//CHAMA A CONEXÃO COM O BANCO DE DADOS
require('../db/conexao.php');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title><?php echo $VarEmp ;?></title>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='end']").blur(function(){
      var $cep    = $("input[name='cep']");
      var $cidade = $("input[name='cidade']");
      var $bairro = $("input[name='bairro']");
      var $estado = $("input[name='estado']");


      $cep.val('Carregando...');
      $cidade.val('Carregando...');
      $bairro.val('Carregando...');
      $estado.val('Carregando...');

        $.getJSON(
          '../functions/functionCEP.php',
          { end: $( this ).val() },
          function( json )
          {

            $cep.val( json.Jcep );
            $cidade.val( json.Jcidade);
            $bairro.val( json.Jbairro);
            $estado.val( json.Jestado);
          }
        );
    });
  });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<!--INICIO NAVBAR-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CLIENTES</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.php">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         CADASTRO
         <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="../">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        VOLTAR
        </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<!--FINAL NAVBAR-->

<!--INICIO CONTAINER-->
<div class="container">
  <!--ROW PAINEL-->
    <!--INICIO PAINEL-->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-body">
       <!--INICIO breadcrumb-->
       <ol class="breadcrumb">
         <li><a href="../">INICIO</a></li>
         <li class="active">CADASTRO</li>
       </ol>
       <!--FINAL breadcrumb-->

      <!--INICIO FORMULARIO DE CADASTRO-->
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>DADOS CADASTRAIS</legend>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
               <label for="telefone">TELEFONE</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="SOMENTE NUMEROS">
             </div>
           </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="nome">NOME</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="NOME DO CLIENTE">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
              <label for="rg">RG</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rg" name="rg" placeholder="SOMENTE NUMEROS">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
              <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cpf" name="cpf" placeholder="SOMENTE NUMEROS">
              </div>
            </div>       
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-2">
                 <label for="cep">CEP</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cep" name="cep" placeholder="SOMENTE NUMEROS">
                 </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                 <label for="end" >ENDERECO</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="end" name="end" placeholder="DIGITE ENDERECO">
               </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                 <label for="num">NUMERO</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num" name="num" placeholder="NUMERO">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                 <label for="comp">COMPLEMENTO</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="comp" name="comp" placeholder="COMPLEMENTO">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="bairro">BAIRRO</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bairro" name="bairro" placeholder="BAIRRO DO CLIENTE">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
              <label for="cidade">CIDADE</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cidade" name="cidade" placeholder="CIDADE DO CLIENTE">
              </div>   
              <div class="col-md-2">
              <label for="estado">ESTADO</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="estado" name="estado" placeholder="SIGLA">
              </div>            
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
              <label for="email">E-MAIL</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL DO CLIENTE">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                 <br>
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">CADASTRAR</button>
               </div>
              </div>
        </fieldset>
        <!--FINAL FORMULARIO DE CADASTRO-->
      </form>

     <!--FINAL PAINEL-->
     </div>
    </div>
    <!--FINAL COL-MD-12-->
   </div>
   <!--FINAL ROW-->
  </div>
  <!--FINAL CONTAINER-->
 </div>
<!--FINAL CONTAINER-->  

  </body>
</html>
```

E tenho a seguinte função:

```
<?php
  /**
   * função que devolve em formato JSON os dados do cliente
   */
  function retorna( $end, $db )
  {
    $sql = "SELECT 
 r.endereco_cep        AS CEP,
 r.endereco_logradouro AS ENDERECO, 
 b.bairro_descricao    AS BAIRRO,
 c.cidade_codigo       AS CODCID,
 c.cidade_descricao    AS CIDADE,
 e.uf_sigla            AS SIGLA,
 e.uf_descricao        AS ESTADO
       FROM 
            cep_endereco AS r
            LEFT JOIN cep_bairro AS b ON b.bairro_codigo = r.bairro_codigo
            LEFT JOIN cep_cidade AS c ON c.cidade_codigo = b.cidade_codigo
            LEFT JOIN cep_uf     AS e ON e.uf_codigo = c.uf_codigo   
                 WHERE 
                  c.cidade_codigo = '3169' 
                  AND r.endereco_logradouro = '{$end}' ";

    $query = $db->query( $sql );

    $arr = Array();
    if( $query->num_rows )
    {
      while( $dados = $query->fetch_object() )
      {
        $arr['Jendereco'] = $dados->ENDERECO;
        $arr['Jcep']      = $dados->CEP;
        $arr['Jbairro']   = $dados->BAIRRO;
        $arr['Jcidade']   = $dados->CIDADE;
        $arr['Jestado']   = $dados->SIGLA;


      }
    }
    else
      $arr['Jcidade'] = 'não encontrado';

    return json_encode( $arr );
  }

if( isset($_GET['end']) )
{
  $db = new mysqli('192.168.0.1', 'root', '', 'cad');
  echo retorna( filter ( $_GET['end'] ), $db );
}

function filter( $var ){
  return $var;
}
```

Se eu digita o endereço corretamente e apertar tab ou clicar em outro campo preenche corretamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais preciso que ele faça igual é mesmo no [jqueryui](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) que é digitar e ele oferecer as opções como,além de preencher todos os campos como já esta sendo feito:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu poderia esta fazendo de errado que não esta dando certo ?

> Obs:segue o retorno da função:

```
{"Jendereco":"RUA A","Jcep":"35052220","Jbairro":"VISTA ALEGRE","Jcidade":"GOVERNADOR VALADARES","Jestado":"MG"}
```

Segue erro que esta retornando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SOLUÇÃO:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('../functions/functionAutoComplete.php', function(data){

            var endereco = [];


                $(data).each(function(key, value) {

                    endereco.push(value.ENDERECO);


                    });
                  $('#end').autocomplete({ source: endereco, minLength: 3});

                  console.log(endereco);


        });

    });


$(document).keydown(function(){
            $("input[name='end']").blur(function(){
                var $cep    = $("input[name='cep']");
                var $cidade = $("input[name='cidade']");
                var $bairro = $("input[name='bairro']");
                var $estado = $("input[name='estado']");


                $cep.val('Carregando...');
                $cidade.val('Carregando...');
                $bairro.val('Carregando...');
                $estado.val('Carregando...');

                $.getJSON(
                    '../functions/functionCEP.php',
                    { end: $( this ).val() },
                    function( json )
                    {

                    $cep.val( json.dados.Jcep );
                    $cidade.val( json.dados.Jcidade);
                    $bairro.val( json.dados.Jbairro);
                    $estado.val( json.dados.Jestado);
                    }
                    );
            });
        });





</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você incluiu o jQuery UI em seu código, mas não o utiliza em lugar algum.

[Na documentação oficial](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default) você pode ver o caso de uso mais simples de todos. O autocomplete é utilizado assim:

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});
```

Você precisa selecionar suas caixas de texto uma a uma com jQuery, e para cada elemento você deve chamar a função `autocomplete` da forma como está no exemplo. Somente assim você terá as caixas de sugestão.

Comment: Inclui,mais sem sucesso:     $.getJSON(
     '../functions/functionCEP.php',
     { end: $( this ).val() },
     function( json )
     {

                       $( "#end" ).autocomplete({
                          source: availableTags
                        });

      $cep.val( json.Jcep );
      $cidade.val( json.Jcidade);
      $bairro.val( json.Jbairro);
      $estado.val( json.Jestado);
     }
     );

Comment: Testei assim também: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Comment: @otaciojb você não pode simplesmente copiar e colar o exemplo na página do jQuery UI. a propriedade source do objeto passado para o método `autocomplete` deve ser a fonte da qual você vai obter os seus dados. E se você quiser obter a partir de uma base de dados, sugiro usar o [TypeAhead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) do Twitter.

Comment: Mais lá eles estão lendo json e eu também, não entendi não pode copiar uma vez que as estruturas são as mesmas, mais blza,vou ver o TypeAhead,Obrigado

Comment: @otaciojb você não tem um objeto chamado `availableTags` no seu código. Você deve fornecer um objeto próprio seu para o valor de source.

Comment: Desculpa a demora no retorno, ali encima eu só exemplifiquei como fiz, mais criei um objeto e ainda assim não da certo, segue meu objeto: {"dados":{"Jendereco":"RUA ALMENARA","Jcep":"35052881","Jbairro":"TURMALINA","Jcidade":"GOVERNADOR VALADARES","Jestado":"MG"}}

Comment: Sabe o que poderia fazer?

Comment: @otaciojb eu sugiro abrir uma pergunta específica só para esse ponto do source. A nova pergunta chamará mais atenção da comunidade e você terá mais pessoas a lhe ajudar. De qualquer forma acho que mais tarde posso elaborar um exemplo.