# Como gerar um código num form HTML que ainda não exista

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho um formulário em HTML com um campo "Código Referência" em que dá a possibilidade ao utilizador de inserir um código para um produto em questão que será, posteriormente, gravado na BD. Como este campo tem de ser único e o utilizador não tem de saber (obviamente) os códigos que já existem, queria incluir, abaixo deste campo, um botão que gerasse um código que não exista na BD e colocasse esse código no input do Código. 
Segue o código HTML com o campo e o botão:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="reference">Código de Referência</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-prepend input-append">
            <input id="reference"  type="text" name="reference" value="<?php
            if (isset($data['dados_produto']['reference']))
                echo $data['dados_produto']['reference'];
            ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group"> 
<div class="controls">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="btn-openform-precos">Gerar Código de Referência</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Gerar um código em javascript não deve ser difícil mas o problema será aceder à BD para verificar que ele já não existe.

Comment: Se você postar a estrutura da tabela e informa qual é o campo do referido código, fica mais fácil da galera ajudar!
Para verificar se o código existe no bd, terá de fazer uma consulta!

Comment: Não aconselho fazer isso pois qualquer valor no lado do cliente pode facilmente ser alterado através do próprio navegador. Gere esse código no lado do servidor.

Comment: Fica a dúvida de como o usuário não pode saber os códigos que já existem, mas deve inserir um novo código, e que deve ser único.

Comment: Não percebi como fazer isso @Marco

Comment: @VítorSá, esqueça meu segundo comentário, entendi o que você quis dizer com o botão que gera o código, mas ainda assim, como disse no primeiro comentário, isso não é algo tão viável visto que pode ser facilmente alterado pelo usuário.

Comment: Você quer que esse código seja exibido para o usuário por algum motivo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o autocomplete do [jquery ui](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) e [AJAX](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js) como utilizei [aqui no meu caso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/195849/autocomplete-com-jquery-e-mysql-n%C3%A3o-lista-as-op%C3%A7%C3%B5es-ao-come%C3%A7ar-a-digitar)

Você faz uma consulta no banco trazendo o retorno em um json, com isso você poderia trazer o próprio código que você quer.

Segue um exemplo basicamente de como poderia ser:

```
<?php
//CHAMA A CONEXÃO COM O BANCO DE DADOS
require('../db/conexao.php');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title><?php echo $VarEmp ;?></title>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='cod']").blur(function(){
      var $cod= $("input[name='cod']");

      $cod.val('Carregando...');


        $.getJSON(
          '../functions/functionCOD.php',
          { cod: $( this ).val() },
          function( json )
          {

            $cod.val( json.Jcod );
          }
        );
    });
  });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <!--INICIO FORMULARIO DE CADASTRO-->
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>DADOS CADASTRAIS</legend>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
              <label for="cod">CÓDIGO</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cod" name="cod" placeholder="CODIGO DO CLIENTE">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                 <br>
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">CADASTRAR</button>
               </div>
              </div>
        </fieldset>
        <!--FINAL FORMULARIO DE CADASTRO-->
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

O seu `functionCOD.php` poderia ser algo assim:

```
<?php
  /**
   * função que devolve em formato JSON os dados do cliente
   */
  function retorna( $cod, $db ){


    $VarStatus =  $cod[0];


    $sql = "SELEC CODIGO+1 FROM CLIENTES WHERE STATUS ='{$VarStatus}'";

    $query = $db->query( $sql );

    $arr = Array();
    if( $query->num_rows )
    {
      while( $dados = $query->fetch_object() )
      {
        $arr['dados']['Jcod'] = $dados-CODIGO



      }
    }
    else
      $arr['dados']['Jcod'] = 'não encontrado';


    return json_encode( $arr );
  }

  if( isset($_GET['cod']) )
  {
    $db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'SISTEMA');

    echo retorna( filter ( $_GET['cod'] ), $db );
  }

  function filter( $var ){
    return $var;
  }
?>
```

Lembrando que é somente um exemplo, mais creio que daria certo